# Laravel/Livewire is not working after hosting on xampp

Tags: laravel-10, livewire-3

I'm quite new to livewire. I'm developing an application using Laravel 10 and Livewire 3.4. This application is working fine with php artisan serve. Also this application is working on xampp except for livewire components. When I inspect the webpage on the browser, the console says "......?id=a27c4ca2 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)" . I know this question is already repeated and there were some answers on the internet too. But non of them worked for me. Please help me to solve this.

In livewire official document, it 's mentioned to change "asset_url =>" to my project root. In my config/livewire.php, it doesn't include "'asset_url'  =>  http://localhost/MyOfficePal/public'," but I manually entered this entry to this file. But it didn't work for me. (MyOfficePal is the project name).

I also try to clear cache, route via php artisan and also tried coumposer dumpautoload -o too.

Your kind help is highly appreciated. Thank you.